# git blame while resolving merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I often rebase a large open source project and there are merge conflicts where I need to figure out who made the change and when in order to decide as to which change to take. So generally what I do is that I go to both repos and look at the file and do a git blame. Is there a mergetool that will provide this info during conflict resolution. I would like to know who made and this change and when for each version. Right now I am using meld.

Answer (score 16):

[Beside gitk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26502090/6309), you can try `git blame -L '/^<<<</,/^>>>>/' -- {filename}`: this is not integrated to a mergetool, but can be done for all conflicted files first.
Then you launch mergetool.

Comment: This is stupidly useful and going into my regular snippets. Can it target folders too, or just a file at a time?

Comment: @liljoshu git blame don't work for directory, as far as I know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260196/how-to-git-blame-a-directory#comment56265439_34260196. You would need to loop over files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55573246/6309

Comment: This is good, before I resolve each file I have to run this command. It's a shame that the mergetool cannot do this for us.

Comment: Just realised that this shows only first conflict in the file but not all!

Comment: @RajPawanGumdal OK: do ask a new question illustrating the issue. That seems an interesting case.